# Leer un array multiple de una base de datos MySql

Tags: php, javascript, html

formulario:

```
         <td>
          <select multiple="multiple" name="aPP[]" id="aPP[]" title="Seleccione los antecedentes patológicos, para seleccionar varios mantenga oprimida la tecla control"> 
            <option value="">Seleccione</option>
            <option value="hipertencion_Arterial," >HTA</option>
            <option value="accidente_cerebro_vascular,">ACV</option>
            <option value="secuelas_de_ACV,">Secuelas de ACV</option>
            <option value="DM_Tipo_I,">DM Tipo I</option>
            <option value="DM_Tipo_II,">DM Tipo II</option>
            <option value="cancer,"> Cancer</option>
            <option value="enfermedad_acido_peptia,">Enfermedad Acido Peptica</option>
            <option value="epoc,">EPOC</option>
            <option value="enfermeded_pulmonar_restrictiva,">Enfermedad Pulmonar Restrictiva</option>
            <option value="enfermedad_genetica,">Enfermedad o Condición Genética</option>
            <option value="enfermedad_congenita,">Enfermedad o condición Congénita</option>
            <option value="Infecciones,">Infecciones</option>
            <option value="oAP">Otras</option>
          </select>
        </td>
```

Para Ver la informacion de la base de datos utilizo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
     require'../class/database.php'; // llamamos al archivo que nos conecta a la base de datos 
    $objData = new Database();
    $sth = $objData->prepare('SELECT * FROM aPP WHERE numeroHC = :numeroHC' );
    $numeroHC = $_GET['numeroHC'];
    $sth->bindParam(':numeroHC',$numeroHC);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    if($result){
?>
 <table width="100%" border="4">        
  for ($i=0; $i< count($result); $i++)
  {;
?> 

  Patologias: <?php echo $result [$i] ['aPP']; 
?>.
```

lo que muestra es :

array yo quiero ver la informacion que selecciona el usuario.
mil gracias

Comment: Que tal Alonso, utiliza el var_dump en lugar el echo `var_dump($result)`

Comment: Esto para saber que contiene el arreglo y que puedas seleccionar los indices y nombres `[$i]['aPP']` correctamente

Comment: Buenas tardes, soy Alonso, quiero dar las gracias por la respuesta y la dedicacion que le han puesto a mi problema, quiero aclarar que el formulario esta completo y las variables estan controladas en otro script, solo que no se los mostré para no hacer muy larga mi pregunta, el problema que tengo es que la informacion que se guarda en la DB es literalmente 'ARRAY' y por logica cuando quiero recuperar lo que el usuario seleccionó lo que me llega es la palabra 'array'

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Uno de los problemas que veo en tu código es que empiezas a construir una tabla HTML pero esta queda incompleta. Cuando esto ocurre no se ve nada en pantalla, porque `<table>` no tiene los elementos `<tr>, <td>` de apertura y cierre adecuado, y porque la misma etiqueta `table` no es cerrada.

Otros motivos pueden hacer que tu código no funcione, como que el dato no haya sido pasado, que no se encuentren datos, etc. Propongo que intentes esto, que controla cualquier eventualidad y crea el elemento `table` completo.

El código está optimizado por esta verificación previa que sirve además para ir solicitando los recursos según se vayan a necesitar. Si estás cocinando, hay momentos para agregar ciertos ingredientes, ¿por qué en programación muchos aprenden malas prácticas, como echar la sal al chuletón mientras está en la plancha? Si se la echas al momento de comértelo la carne estará más tierna... En programación se incluyen y se requieren archivos o se declaran objetos sin siquiera saber si vas a necesitarlos. Es lo que pasaba por ejemplo con la conexión. Si `$numeroHC` no existe es inútil crear una conexión o consultar porque no encontrará nada, por tanto antes de echarla ese ingrediente hay que evaluar el estado de `$numeroHC`.

```
<?php
    $numeroHC = !empty ($_GET['numeroHC']) ? $_GET['numeroHC'] : FALSE;
    if (!$numeroHC) {
        $txtOutput="No se postearon datos, revise su formulario";
    }else{
        require'../class/database.php'; // llamamos al archivo que nos conecta a la base de datos
        $objData = new Database();
        $sth = $objData->prepare('SELECT * FROM aPP WHERE numeroHC = :numeroHC');
        $sth->bindParam(':numeroHC',$numeroHC);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        if(!$result){
            $txtOutput="No se encontraron datos, revise su consulta";
        } else {
            $txtOutput="<table width=\"100%\" border=\"4\">";
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $txtOutput.="<tr>";
                $txtOutput.="<td>Patologías: $row[aPP]</td>";
                $txtOutput.="</tr>";
            }
            $txtOutput.="</table>";
        }
    }
    echo $txtOutput;
?>
```

Comment: sin duda una gran explicación , no sabia lo de la carne :)...!!

Comment: @DiegoAvila yo tampoco, pero alguien que sabe de cocina me lo dijo hace ya tiempo y tenía razón. La sal pone la carne dura por lo que en ese caso es mejor echársela para comértela. Si es guisada claro que hay que echársela durante el guiso, pero si es solo la carne a la parilla o sartén, mejor echársela al momento de comerla. La diferencia es notable. Saludos. :)